# Late 90s early 00s cartoon about space delivery people

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a cartoon on  Nickelodeon or Cartoon network that involved brothers who were delivery people in space.  I know Futurama matches this description, but this is definitely not it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [The Brothers Flub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Flub).

It ran in 1999 (on Nickelodeon) for 26 episodes and featured two brothers; Guapo and Fraz who work as space package couriers

Comment: In the immortal words of Duke Nukem: "D@mn that's annoying."